# Proof of Brun's irrationality critera for infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a proof about Brun's irrationality criteria on the irrationality of a infinite series. I have tried to access the original paper but I cannot find it.

For those who don't know, Brun's criteria states that given a sequence of positive integers a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> such that a<sub>n</sub>/b<sub>n</sub> is strictly increasing and tends to some limit L, if the sequence given by  $$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$ is strictly decreasing, then L is irrational.

Comment: It might be a good idea if you explained what Brun's irrationality criteria is. After all, it's not impossible that someone here could know/figure-out how to prove the theorem, but not know the theorem by name. It would also be more useful to future readers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i edited my post accordingly